# Distribution of this strange combination of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have two independent random variables $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ and we know their CDFs, given by $F_{\gamma_1}(x)$ and $F_{\gamma_2}(x)$. We select a threshold $\gamma_T$ and then we define a random variable $Z$ as follows:

If $\gamma_2 < \gamma_T$, then $Z = \max(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$.

If $\gamma_2 \geq \gamma_T$, then $Z = \gamma_2$.

I am trying to calculate the CDF of $Z$, $F_Z(x)$.

For the first case ($\gamma_2 < \gamma_T$) I know that $F_Z(x) = F_{\gamma_1}(x) \cdot F_{\gamma_2}(x)$, however I am unable to calculate the CDF for the second case ($\gamma_2 \geq \gamma_T$).

For the second case I have tried $F_Z(x) = F_{\gamma_1}(\gamma_T) \cdot F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T) + F_{\gamma_2}(x) - F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)$ but comparing to simulations it doesn't seem to be the correct solution.

I have also checked Example 6-17 in page 193 of the book of Papoulis (4th edition), which I think is related, but I'm not sure how to do the calculation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend going straight from the definition of $F_Z(x)$ as "the probability that $Z<x$". Hint: if $x>\gamma_T$, then $Z<x$ means that either $\gamma_T\le \gamma_2<x$ or both $\gamma_2<\gamma_T$ and $\gamma_1<x$.

Answer (score 3):

The threshold  partitions the range of $\gamma_2$ into $I_l:=(-\infty,\gamma_T)$ and $I_u:= [\gamma_T,\infty)$.

We need to use conditional probability to get the definition of $Z$:

$$P(Z\leq z) = P(\gamma_2 \in I_l)P(Z\leq z|\gamma_2 \in I_l) + P(\gamma_2 \in I_u)P(Z\leq z|\gamma_2 \in I_u)$$

**Case 1: $\gamma_2 \in I_l$**

$$P(Z\leq z|\gamma_2 \in I_l) = P(\gamma_1\leq z)P(\gamma_2\leq z|\gamma_2\in I_l)=F_{\gamma_1}(z)\cdot\min\left(1,\frac{F_{\gamma_2}(z)}{F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}\right)$$

**Case 2: $\gamma_2 \in I_u$**
$$P(Z\leq z|\gamma_2 \in I_u) = P(\gamma_2\leq z|\gamma_2\in I_u)=\mathbf{1}_{I_u}(z)\cdot\left(\frac{F_{\gamma_2}(z)-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}{1-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}\right)$$

Putting these into the overall $P(z\leq Z)$ equation we get:

$$P(Z\leq z) = F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)\cdot F_{\gamma_1}(z)\cdot\min\left(1,\frac{F_{\gamma_2}(z)}{F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}\right) + (1-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T))\cdot\mathbf{1}_{I_u}(z)\cdot\left(\frac{F_{\gamma_2}(z)-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}{1-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)}\right)$$

Simplifying we get

$$P(Z\leq z) = F_{\gamma_1}(z)\cdot\min\left(F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T),F_{\gamma_2}(z)\right) + \mathbf{1}_{I_u}(z)\cdot \left(F_{\gamma_2}(z)-F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)\right)$$

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for your great answer! Do you mind if I ask a variation of the question, what would be the result if the following line of the problem is changed (the sum instead of the maximum): 

If $\gamma_2 < \gamma_T$, then $Z = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2$.

I was able to resolve this other version of the problem using a different method, but my method didn't seem to work with the original problem. If you could give the details, that would be a great help for me to understand the solution.

Comment: @João that's actually a bit tougher -- are each of the CDFs differentiable?

Comment: Yes all CDFs are differentiable. The way I obtained the solution was first calculating the PDF for the lower interval as the convolution of the PDFs and the CDF by integrating the PDF, that gives me the expression of $F_Z(z)$ for $\gamma_2 < \gamma_T$ which is correct. Then I use equation (6-38) of Papoulis to integrate that PDF until $\gamma_T$ and add to it the expression $F_{\gamma_2}(z) - F_{\gamma_2}(\gamma_T)$ to get another expression for $\gamma_2 \geq \gamma_T$.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to obtain the solution using something similar to your response, I'm just amazed by how elegant and beautiful it is, much more than what I have. Sorry if I ask too much, your response is already very helpful anyway!

Comment: @João unfortunately no -- unless your random variables are both from the same class of infinitely divisible distributions then the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables requires convolution. My solution worked because you are only every working with the distribution of a single variable not a sum.

Comment: True, I understand now. Thanks again for your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: @João no problem -- happy to help :)